# Spring Boot Spring Security 5, OAuth2Login Not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security

We have developed our own Authorization Server which we are using for Single Sign on
we developed our client app with the annotation @EnableOAuth2Sso with the following configuration

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
      .and()
      .antMatcher("/**")
      .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).authorizeRequests()
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/","/login/**","/callback/url/**","/error**","/webjars/**","/favicon.ico**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)
        .and().httpBasic()
        .and()
         .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
```

it was working fine

but just now I want to use the  .oauth2Login() features comes with Spring Security 5 so I changed the annotation to @EnableOAuth2Client from @EnableOAuth2Sso and used the following configuration

```
  @Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
}
```

now while compiling I am getting the following error messages

```
Description:

Method springSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
- Bean method 'clientRegistrationRepository' in 'OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration' not loaded because OAuth2 
Clients Configured Condition registered clients is not available
Action:
Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' in your configuration.
```

So  I changed my application.properties from

```
security.oauth2.client.auto-approve-scopes=read,write
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=http://localhost:8080/xxxxx/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=http://localhost:8080/xxxxx/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.client.client-id=xxx
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=secret
security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirect-uri=http://localhost:11001/xxx/login/oauth2/code
security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=http://localhost:11001/xxx/login/oauth2/code
security.oauth2.client.useCurrentUri=false
security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
security.oauth2.client.grant-type=authorization_code, refresh_token
```

to the following

```
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client-id=xxx_client
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client-secret=secret
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code,refresh_token
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.redirect-uri=http://localhost:11001/xxx/login/oauth2/code
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.scope=read,write
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client-name=xxxxx
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxx.client-authentication-method=POST
 spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.token-uri=http://localhost:8080/xxxxx/oauth/token
 spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.authorization-uri=http://localhost:8080/xxxxx/oauth/authorize
 spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8080/xxxxx/validateLogin
```

But it displays a welcome page where our authorization server name is shown i.e xxxxx and if I click that link it does not connect to our authorization server.

I have confusion here what is the difference between @EnableOAuth2Sso and @EnableOAuth2Client Why when we use OAuth2Login() we need to change our properties

Is there any good example of using OAuth2Login with Custom Oauth2 provider (instead of google,facebook,okta etc)I searched google but no where any example provided

Comment: `@EnableOAuth2Sso` is prior to Spring Security 5 i.e the times when Spring OAuth was in a seperate project than Spring Security 4

Comment: Also all the props `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration` should be followed by `registrationId` which could be called custom. Then also after `*.client.provider` you would provide providerId

Comment: Thanks I followed a link  https://dzone.com/articles/build-an-oauth-20-authorization-server-with-spring and it is useful and  now I get the flow correctly  but I did not use Okta as we are using our customized authorization server. but the issue once the client app url is accessed is shows a generated page where our Authroization server name is shown after clicking the link only it takes to login page is there any way to avoid the welcome page as we have only one authentication server. The welcome page is useful when user needs to select the type of login for example facebook,google etc.